# Loop through nested array, find specific leaf node by id, and remove it

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9x10u5n/)

I have a nested array with at most 6 levels. The 6th level is called `gls`, which holds objects of `gl`s from a database. What I need to do is find a specific `gl` and remove it from the overall array. I'm able to find the specific element with the following function;

```
const removeFromData = function(nodes, id) {
  return nodes.some((node) => {
    if (node.gls) {
      node.gls.forEach((gl) => {
        if (gl.id === id) {
          console.log(gl, id);
        }
      });
    } else if (node.children) {
      return removeFromData(node.children, id);
    }
  });
}
```

However, I'm struggling to actually remove it from the `data` array. Trying to get the index by doing `data.indexOf(gl)` obviously returns `-1` as it doesn't search through the nested elements. What's the best way to accomplish this?

```js
const id = 1000;

const data = [{
    "id": 1, "name": "Node 1", "children": [{
      "id": 2, "name": "Node 1.1", "children": [{
        "id": 4, "name": "Node 1.1.1", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 1000, "name": "GL1", "code": "0100"
        }, {
          "id": 1001, "name": "GL2", "code": "0200"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": 5, "name": "Node 1.1.2", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 2000, "name": "GL3", "code": "0300"
        }, {
          "id": 2001, "name": "GL4", "code": "0400"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 3, "name": "Node 1.2", "children": [{
        "id": 6, "name": "Node 1.2.1", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 3000, "name": "GL5", "code": "0500"
        }, {
          "id": 3001, "name": "GL6", "code": "0600"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 7, "name": "Node 2", "children": [{
      "id": 8, "name": "Node 2.1", "children": [{
        "id": 9, "name": "Node 2.1.1", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 4000, "name": "GL7", "code": "0700"
        }, {
          "id": 4001, "name": "GL8", "code": "0800"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
];


let removeFromData = function(nodes, id) {
  return nodes.some((node) => {
    if (node.gls) {
      node.gls.forEach((gl) => {
        if (gl.id === id) {
          document.querySelector('#target').innerText = `found ${gl.name}, ${gl.id} with needle ${id}`;
        }
      });
    } else if (node.children) {
      return removeFromData(node.children, id);
    }
  });
}

removeFromData(data, id);
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
```

Comment: remove means splice or return an array without? please add some data and the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` passes three arguments to the callback, the second of which is the index of the entry being visited. So you can use that index with `splice` (if you want to modify in place):

```
const removeFromData = function(nodes, id) {
  return nodes.some((node) => {
    if (node.gls) {
      node.gls.forEach((gl, index) => {
// -----------------------^^^^^^^
        if (gl.id === id) {
          //console.log(gl, id);
          node.gls.splice(index, 1); // <=== Removes the entry
        }
      });
    } else if (node.children) {
      return removeFromData(node.children, id);
    }
  });
}
```

---

I notice you're using `some`, which suggests you want to stop when you've found the entry and perhaps also return a flag indicating success/failure. If so, I'd use `some` instead of `forEach` on the `nodes.gls` search or possibly use `findIndex` instead. With `some`:

```
const removeFromData = function(nodes, id) {
  return nodes.some((node) => {
    if (node.gls) {
      return node.gls.some((gl, index) => {
        if (gl.id === id) {
          //console.log(gl, id);
          node.gls.splice(index, 1); // <=== Removes the entry
          return true;
        }
      });
    } else if (node.children) {
      return removeFromData(node.children, id);
    }
  });
}
```

With `findIndex`:

```
const removeFromData = function(nodes, id) {
  return nodes.some((node) => {
    if (node.gls) {
      const index = node.gls.findIndex((gl) => {
        return gl.id === id;
      });
      if (index === -1) {
        return false;
      }
      node.gls.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
    } else if (node.children) {
      return removeFromData(node.children, id);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The first example, before your edit, already worked. Would there be any specific benefit to using either `some` or `findIndex`?

Comment: @Alex - There are two benefits: 1. You stop looping through `nodes.gls` once you find the one you're looking for. (Not a big deal unless there are hundreds of thousands of entries in it.) 2. The return value from `removeFromData` is correct, whereas in the first one the return value is always `false`, whether the data was found or not.